# Can't add the permissions in MainActivity.java

Tags: android, android-activity, permissions, runtime-error, manifest

Added the permission in the manifest but while adding this permission in MainActivity.java then it shows DYNAMIC_RECEIVER_NOT_EXPORTED_PERMISSION,and it showing the error: package manifest does not exists, so what should I do

I added the permission of SEND_SMS In manifest and try to use that permission in MainActivity.java by using Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS but after Manifest.permission. it not showing any permission it only showing the DYNAMIC_RECEIVER_NOT_EXPORTED_PERMISSION